# OpenGL - Как отобразить текстуру так, чтобы её размер в окне был таким же как и реальный размер

Tags: .net, winforms, opengl, pascalabc.net, 2d

Пишу 2D игру на OpenGL+Tao.OpenGL и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
допустим есть картинка с размерами 106x182(она в архиве) пикселей и нужно сделать так, чтобы в окне она отображалась с таким же размером.
Я так понимаю что надо как-то плясать от размеров экрана и соотношений сторон экрана, но ничего работоспособного в голову не приходит.
Единственное что у меня получилось, так это подогнать формулу отображения текстуры под свой размер экрана(1366x768), но если изменить разрешение экрана например на 1280x768, то получается полная фигня, текстуры размываются по всему экрану.

Управление:
W - вверх
A - влево
S - вниз
D - вправо
I - Открыть инвентарь
Также можно мышкой перемещать предметы в инвентаре и нажимать на рабочую кнопку "крестик"(сверху справа в инвентаре) чтобы закрыть инвентарь.

Всё наработки в [архиве](https://yadi.sk/d/dLJA7Aq8HknLqA).

Весь код в "test.pas", но запускать игру через "Launcher.exe" !

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь, что кто-то станет качать архив, чтобы посмотреть на код. Уж лучше гитхаб. А если кода немного, то лучше поместить в сам вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Решил вот так:

```
glOrtho(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, 0, -1, 1);
```